# Infinite vertical ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a vertical ScrollView and I want to make it infinite. When the last item is shown i want the first item to appear and so one. Anybody can give me some advice?

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollViewId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_weight="0.49">
<!-- Right button bar -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_bar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/buttonbar_height"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/ButtonBar.Bottom">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Button.Borderless"
        android:src="?attr/iconHome"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/movies"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Button.Borderless"
        android:src="?attr/iconMovies"
        android:contentDescription="@string/movies"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tv_shows"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Button.Borderless"
        android:src="?attr/iconTvShows"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tv_shows"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: two advices. 1) don't do it. 2) use a ListView instead of a ScrollView

Comment: Ok, I will try a ListView, But I still don't know how to make it cycle

Comment: fair enough. If I were in you I would start understanding how the ListView widget works

Comment: For listview also, you can get the end of the listview and then add more elements to the adapter of the listview and then call notifydatasetchanged() for the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want a vertical scrollview with "INFINITE" scrolling! But anyways, my idea of doing is :

For the first time, add the elements in the scrollview. Then, you can find out the end of the scrollview. When end of the scrollview is reached, repopulate the scrollview with the same elements added before under the already populated elements. In this way, whenever the scrollview will come to it's end element, keep populating with more and more elements.

To find the bottom of scrollview, you can refer this 
[link](http://marteinn.se/blog/android-determinate-when-scrollview-has-reached-the-bottom/) or similar such links.